# UITextField in UITableViewCell throws -[UITextInputTraits length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: uitableview

I have created a UITableViewController and corresponding XIB to generate a form.

In the XIB, I have a TableView and a UITableViewCell.  Inside the UITableViewCell is a UILabel and UITextField.

The FileOwner is set to the DiaryEntryViewController (UITableViewController).

I then push it onto the nav stack with:

```
    DiaryEntryViewController *entry = [[DiaryEntryViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DiaryEntry" bundle:nil];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:entry animated:YES];
    [entry release];
```

DiaryViewEntryController.h has:

```
  IBOutlet UITableViewCell *cell0;
  IBOutlet UITextField* title;

  @property(nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet UITableViewCell *cell0;
  @property(nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet UITextField *title;
```

The @synthesize is set in .m.

In the XIB, I connect the UITableViewCell to "cell0" outlet and UITextField to "title" outlet.  When I run the code, it breaks on:

```
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:entry animated:YES];
```

The error I get is:

```
   -[UITextInputTraits length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

If I disconnect the UITextField (title) outlet, the view displays.  It's only when the UITextField is connected to the outlet that it bombs.

I don't have 'length' anywhere in my code.  It dies right after ViewDidLoad is completed.

Any thoughts on this?  I tried creating a new UITextField with no success.

Answer (score 4):

I just ran into the same problem you describe above. The issue seems to be related to using title as the name of the UITTextField. I noticed that our fields were both called title, changed mine, and it worked. Weird problem, eh?

Cheers,

-Rolf.

Comment: I don't understand why doing [Ctrl + Z] did not release the attribute from Interface Builder but did remove the entry from the header file. Weird.